# How to change style of tooltip in Odoo v14?

Tags: css, odoo

I want to change the style of Odoo tooltip (help="My help text" option in fields). But I am having probles including my custom style. I want to change the color of the tooltip box, heading and font size.
**Hint:** I have backend_theme_v14, so maybe i need to put my style on top of that.
This is what I have done so far:

### assets.xml

Note that i already had a js file included

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend" inherit_id="web.assets_backend" name="confirmation_assets" >
            <xpath expr="script[last()]" position="after">
                <script type="text/javascript"
                       src="/cusaf/static/src/js/confirmation.js"/>
            </xpath>
        </template>

      <template id="assets_backend_css" name="tooltip_assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">     
                 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/cusaf/static/src/css/tooltip.css"/>
            </xpath>       
         </template>  
    </data>
</odoo>
```

### tooltip.css

I don't need every option. I just want to change the color of the tooltip box. the heading and make the font size bigger

```
/* Tooltip container */
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted rgb(80, 42, 231); /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
}

/* Tooltip text */
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: rgb(42, 206, 75);
  color: rgb(205, 35, 35);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
 
  /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */
.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tooltip colors are defined as [varibles](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/static/src/scss/primary_variables.scss#L34-L39), to customize theminherit the [_assets_primary_variables](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/views/webclient_templates.xml#L12) template.

***Example:***

*xml:*

```
<template id="tooltip_colors" name="Customize tooltip colors" inherit_id="web._assets_primary_variables">
    <xpath expr="." position="inside">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="/cusaf/static/src/scss/tooltip.scss"/>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

*scss:*

```scss
$o-tooltip-background-color: rgb(42, 206, 75);
$o-tooltip-color: rgb(205, 35, 35);
```

Tooltip style is defined in [tooltip.scss](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/addons/web/static/src/scss/tooltip.scss) file. To change the tooltip text font weight to bold, you can use the following:

```scss
.tooltip-inner {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```